# php select id where id equals to 1 and 2

Tags: php, equals

How to select id's that equals to two values, like id='1,2'

here is what I have:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menus WHERE active='1' AND lock=('1' ,'3') ") or die (mysql_error());
```

i'm new to mysql

Comment: Technically, an id can't have a value of 1 and of 2 at the same time, except in a universe of quantum uncertainty: do you mean 1 OR 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menus WHERE active='1' AND lock IN (1 ,3) ") or die   (mysql_error());
```

or this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menus WHERE active='1' AND (lock = 1 OR lock = 3 ") or die   (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, and thanks everyone for help appreciated :)

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do with it. (I mean on question for what you post a link)

Comment: The comments section is not a forum for advertising other questions. If users want to answer your question, they will. Rather than trying to lure users from one post to another, you should focus your energy on making your questions as clear and relevant as possible.

Comment: @zeantsoi yes sure i would love to accept it right away if i could , if you know or don't you have to wait for 10 min to accept the correct answer, anyways, i posted the link because no one answered correctly so i need it soo bad.

Comment: What is the num['id']? What you mean to get from it? where is your query for it?

Comment: lets talk in there, and also did you check the image posted there, it's a bit hard to explain.

Comment: Yes I see the image, but I don't understand what you want from it. Unfortunately I can't talk there because I don't have the options for posting the comment on questions or answers which are not mine.

Comment: ok, i'm trying to select links from table1 that is not in table2, so if the link is stored in table2 we don't display it, i'm trying to do that but i'm getting different id's, http://pastebin.com/aXa19J4U

Comment: Ok, I understand what you need. I'll post you some solution, and you test it and try to adapt it on your code.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `IN` keyword.

So the SQL statement would be:

`SELECT * FROM menus WHERE active='1' AND lock IN ('1', '3')`

Don't forget to index things kids!

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp